# Existence of a map between automorphism group of universal covers

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a holomorphic map of holomorphic manifolds. You can assume that $dimY=1$. Let $\tilde X$ and $\tilde Y$ be universal covers of $X$ and $Y$ with group of holomorphic automorphisms $Aut(\tilde X)$ and $Aut(\tilde Y)$. Do we get a homomorphism $Aut(\tilde X)\to Aut(\tilde Y)$ in general?

Comment: Automorphism group in which category? You may be asking about the induced map on fundamental groups.

Comment: I think I clarrified this in my question. Automorphism in the category of holomorphic manifolds. So $Aut(\tilde X)$ is the group of holomorphic automorphisms of $\tilde X$. Of course $\pi_{1}(X)\subseteq Aut(\tilde X)$ but I am interested in the full group of automorphisms of $\tilde X$ not only those which cover the coverings map $\tilde X\to X$ (i.e. $\pi_{1}(X)$)

Comment: The question is definitely unclear, it admits some trivial answers which, of course, is not what you're looking for (e.g. you always have the trivial homomorphism).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is negative. For instance, let $X$ be a compact quotiont of the unit ball in ${\mathbb C}^2$ by a discrete torsion-free subgroup of $PU(2,1)$, and $Y$ be a hyperbolic Riemann surface. There are many examples where there exists a nonconstant holomorphic map $f: X\to Y$ (say, if $b_1(X)\ne 0$ then there is always one, for some $Y$), but, clearly, there are no nontrivial homomorphisms $PU(2,1)\to PU(1,1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In this example $Y$ is non-compact. Can it be that if we assume $Y$ to be a compact curve, there exists a homomorphism?

Comment: @DariusMath: In my examples $Y$ is compact.

Comment: Ah, OK. I thought by hyperbolic Riemann surface you mean a Riemann surface with a number of points removed.

Comment: The standard definition of a hyperbolic Riemann surface is the one whose universal cover is biholomorphic to the unit disk. For instance, among compact Riemann surfaces this is equivalent to genus $>1$.